# array becomes string after working of useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The idea is to change 1st element of the array (boolean) from false to true and back.
I tried to do it with useState hook, but it works just 1 time from false to true and if I press the button 'Do it' again - there is the error called 'Cannot create property '0' on boolean 'true'.
I realized, that when I tap 'Do it' - the array does not become anymore array, it is string. We can see that in the console using button 'check', so to solve this problem I need to somehow save the array during the hook process, isnt't it?

code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function App() {


let [mass, setMass] = useState([false, true, false])

const check1 = () => {
    console.log(mass)
}




const check2 = () => {setMass(mass1 => mass1[0] = !mass1[0])}

    return (
        <div className='wrapper'>
            <button onClick={check1}>cheeck</button>
            <button onClick={check2}>Do it</button>

        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `mass` starts as an array of boolean values and then you set it to a single boolean value - `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that your updater function `mass1 => mass1[0] = !mass1[0]` is returning a boolean. The function that you pass to `setMass()` should return the new value that you want to update `mass` to be, you should not modify `mass1` directly. Currently the assignment operator `=` will return whatever you've assigned to the right-hand side of the `=`, so you'll get a boolean back (not a string). Instead, change your updater function to return a new array with the first value negated:

```
setMass(([first,...rest]) => [!first, ...rest]);
```

The above uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull out the first item from your array argument, and then uses the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) to re-build your array which is then retuned to be the new value of `mass` upon the next render.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  let [mass, setMass] = useState([false, true, false])

  const check1 = () => {
    console.log(mass)
  }

  const check2 = () => setMass(([first, ...rest]) => [!first,...rest]);

  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <button onClick={check1}>cheeck</button>
      <button onClick={check2}>Do it</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace `setMass(mass1 => mass1[0] = !mass1[0])` with

```js
setMass(mass1 => {
  mass1[0] = !mass1[0];
  return mass1;
})
```

because otherwise it returns the value of `!mass1[0]` and assigns that as the new value for `mass`, which is `true` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

why not just do it like

```
const check2 = () => {
let newMass = [...mass];
newMass[0] = !newMass[0];
setMass(newMass);

}
```

by doing so it will increase readability and you can change the array in Whatever way you want and set it back.